# Get only innerHTML from website?

Tags: powershell

So I have the following code to pull a snippet of HTML from a website.

This works kind of, in the `parse.txt` file I can see `innerHTML` with exactly the HTML I want.

However the HTML file has a lot more in it, it has all the headers and footers, this isn't displayed in the `innerHTML` object in the text file.

All I want to do is have just that object ( inner HTML ) saved in the HTML file.

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.silent = $false
$ie.navigate2("www.website.com/job1")
$ie.Visible = $true
while($ie.busy) {start-sleep 1}

# grab the table html
$ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName("div") | Where{ $_.className -eq 'job-template__wrapper' } | Out-file "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Parse.txt"
$ie.Document.body.innerHTML  | Out-file "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Parse.html"

$ie.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out, probably not the best way of doing it but here is the code:

```
# Counters
$i = 1
$page = 1


# Main loop : goes until you have x amount of job JobAds
# This isnt 100% accurate it will stop after the foreach loop below finishes, 
#   so you may end up with more than x but never less
while($i -le 2000) 
{
    # IE connection
    $ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
    $ie.Visible = $true # false for silent run
    $ie.silent = $false # false for silent run
    $ie.navigate2("https://www.website.com.au/page?page=$page")

    # wait until ie has finished
    while($ie.busy) {start-sleep 1} 

    # Grab the 22 job links from the set seek page
    $site = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.website.com.au/page
    $site.Links.Href | Sort-Object | Get-Unique > C:\Users\user\Desktop\links.txt
    $links = @(Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\links.txt | Where-Object { $_ -like '*/job/*' })

    # loop through each job link
    foreach ( $link in $links )
    {
        # Connect to job site
        $ie.navigate2("http://www.website.com.au" + $link)
        while($ie.busy) {start-sleep 1}


        # Download and copy to HTML
        $ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName("div") | Where{ $_.className -eq 'job-template__wrapper' } 
        $ie.Document.body.innerHTML  > "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web_scrape\scrape$i.html"

        # Store in variable
        $content= Get-Content "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web_scrape\scrape$i.html" | Out-String

        # Remove header / footer
        $start= $content.indexof('</style>') +8
        $end= $content.indexof("</span>", $start)
        $length =$end - $start
        $content.substring($start, $length) | out-file "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web_scrape\scrape$i.html"


        # Add html tags for word conversion
        '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC >' + (Get-Content "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web_scrape\scrape$i.html" -Raw) | Set-Content "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web_scrape\scrape$i.html"
        '<HTML>' + (Get-Content "C:\Users\user\web_scrape\scrape$i.html" -Raw) | Set-Content "C:\Users\user\web_scrape\scrape$i.html"
        Add-Content  -Path "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web_scrape\scrape$i.html" -Value '</HTML>'

        # Set file variables
        $htmlFile = ('C:\Users\owain.esau\Desktop\web_scrape\scrape' + $i + '.html');
        $docFile = ('C:\Users\owain.esau\Desktop\web_scrape\word\scrape' + $i + '.docx');

        # Convert html to word
        htmlToWord $htmlFile  $docFile

        $i += 1

    }

    $page += 1
    $ie.quit()

}
```